# Scala: Return all sequences between start and end in a list

Tags: scala

I have a list of integers

```scala
val list = List(1,21,1,3,5,21)
```

and I want a method

```scala
def findSequences(list: List[Int], start: Int, end: Int): List[List[Int]] = {
  ...
}
```

which finds all the sequences starting with `start` and ending with `end` inside `list`.

So the result I want is

```scala
findSequences(list, 1, 21) 

>> List(List(1,21), List(1,3,5,21))
```

Edit:

For clarity, suppose we treat the values as string.

Say we have `start = "dog"` and `end = "cat"` and we have a list

```scala
List(dog, elephant, cat, snail, dog, duck, cat)
```

then we want the output

```scala
>> List(List(dog, elephant, cat), List(dog, duck, cat)
```

Comment: By _"all sequences"_ it looks like you mean _all sequences of **ascending values**_. Is that correct?

Comment: @jwvh It does not have to be ascending values. Also, we can assume that there will be no same values twice in a row. So `1,2,2,3` will not be possible.

We can treat the problem with String instead of Int. 
Say we have `start = "dog"` and `end= "cat"` and we have a list
`dog, elephant, cat, snail, dog, duck, cat`, then we want the output `List(List(dog, elephant, cat), List(dog, duck, cat)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own very simple tail-recursive function.

```scala
def findSequences[A](list: List[A], start: A, end: A): List[List[A]] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[A], currentList: List[A], picking: Boolean, acc: List[List[A]]): List[List[A]] =
    (remaining, picking) match {
      case (a :: as, true) =>
        if (a == end)
          loop(
            remaining = as,
            currentList = List.empty,
            picking = false,
            acc = (a :: currentList).reverse :: acc
          )
        else
          loop(
            remaining = as,
            a :: currentList,
            picking = true,
            acc
          )
      
      case (a :: as, false) =>
        if (a == start)
          loop(
            remaining = as,
            currentList = a :: Nil,
            picking = true,
            acc
          )
        else
          loop(
            remaining = as,
            currentList = List.empty,
            picking = false,
            acc
          )
      
      case (Nil, _) =>
        acc.reverse
    }
  
  loop(
    remaining = list,
    currentList = List.empty,
    picking = false,
    acc = List.empty
  )
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```scala
val data = List("dog", "elephant", "cat", "snail", "dog", "duck", "cat")
val result = findSequences(data, start = "dog", end = "cat")
// result: List[List[String]] = List(List(dog, elephant, cat), List(dog, duck, cat))
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/FV9dKGyCTJOZwmVM3SVvtw)*.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done with `unfold()`. (Scala 2.13.x)

```
def findSequences[A](list  : List[A]
                    ,start : A
                    ,end   : A): List[List[A]] =
  List.unfold(list){ as =>
    val x = as.indexOf(start)
    val y = as.indexOf(end, x)
    Option.when(x >= 0 && y > x)(as.slice(x,y+1),as.drop(y))
  }

findSequences(List(1,21,1,3,5,21), 1,21)
findSequences(List("dog", "elephant", "cat", "snail"
                 , "dog", "duck", "cat"), "dog","cat")

//res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 21), List(1, 3, 5, 21))
//res1: List[List[String]] = List(List(dog, elephant, cat)
//                              , List(dog, duck, cat))
```